# Using postgresql to flag a word after a phrase

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field called TEXT1 which contains the following text below in quotes. Is there a way where I can flag for instances where the word orange is being mentioned AFTER the Excluding This portion of the text?

I've tried doing where TEXT1 is not like %orange% but that would get rid of instances where the Including This portion of the text contains the word orange and the Excluding This portion didn't contain the word orange. Basically I need help with a function that will flag for when the word orange is mentioned after the phrase Excluding This within the TEXT1 field in my table.

```
"Including This    
The best fruit is an orange    
Excluding This    
The worst fruit is an orange
"
```

Comment: What do you mean "flag"?

Comment: flag meaning making a case when statement and just coding the end variable as a 1 or 0 flag.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for full text search:

```
WHERE to_tsvector('english', textcol) @@
      to_tsquery('english', 'The <-> best <-> fruit <-> is <-> an <-> orange & ! (The <-> worst <-> fruit <-> is <-> an <-> orange)')
```

Comment: I like this but is there a way where we can eliminate the need for 'the worst fruit' part? All i need to see is if the keyword orange is somewhere in the text AFTER the keyphrase 'excluding this'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no expression for "occurs arbitrarily many words after". You can use `<5>` for "occurs 5 words after".